# Kotlin: Destructuring in lambda parameters

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to iterate over a list of objects/pairs like so:

```
val list = listOf(Pair(1,2),Pair(2,3))

list.forEach { first, second ->
     first + second
}
```

Following doesn't work either:

```
list.forEach { (first, second) in it ->
         first + second
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can destructure the pair directly in the argument list. You are only missing the parenthesis in your first example.

```
list.forEach { (first, second) ->
  first + second
}
```